# userid from asp.net Membership Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm using the asp.net login control for user authentication. I also have the userID in many tables in my application and for now (development purposes), the userID is an int that I'm making up.
However, I'd like to start using the userID of the framework in my tables. Where and how do I access the actual userID and what's its datatype?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `ProviderUserKey` member of the `MembershipUser` object, like this:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
string id = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `aspnet_Users` Table there is a  `UserId` field with the `uniqueidentifier` datatype.

You could [add the membership table into your own database](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203214/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/040506-1.aspx) instead of a separated one.